# delete operation - asp.net mvc - general feedback - styling issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

It is bad practise to perform a delete operation via get request so I have implemented a delete 'post' as asp.net mvc does only support post + get requests (as far as I know).

Please note that I try to avoid javascript/jquery where I could easily perform delete requests (even puts).

I have placed forms on the page for each delete of an item. I have also managed to style the post/submit button to look like a link but things are still not looking very nice. The delete ‘link’ is slightly offset. This is roughly the code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Deletex", "xs", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "deleteForm" }))
{ %>
<%= x.Name %>                                           
<%= Html.Hidden("Id", x.Id)%>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="link_button" /> 
<% } %>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.link_button
{
    background-color:white;
    border:0;
    color:#034af3;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:1em;
    font-family:inherit;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.deleteForm
{
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Did somone else style this succesfully?

Do you have any further feedback reagarding delete ‘posts’ and asp.mvc?

Is this the right way to do things?

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot help you about styling, just a little clarification about the HTTP verbs. ASP.NET MVC supports all the verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE - the problem comes from most browsers that only support GET and POST. You could simulate them using the [HttpMethodOverride](https://web.archive.org/web/20200922122326/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/01/08/implementing-a-delete-link-with-mvc-2-and-httpmethodoverride.aspx) helper:

```
<%= Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete) %>
```

and in your controller action:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Destroy(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please point to a link which details this a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: There's the official documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407388.aspx The method basically adds a hidden field inside your form which when sent to the server the ASP.NET routing engine will recognize and select the proper action method to invoke.

Comment: Thanks I understand this a bit better now. Just curious what is the advantage of doing a 'simulated delete/put request' (using, for example, Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Delete)) over a 'delete/put post request'? thanks.

Comment: @csetzkorn The advantage is that you've built an application according to proper REST/HTTP conventions and semantics - the fact that browsers don't support it is unfortunate, but browsers aren't the only HTTP clients in existence, and the X-HTTPMethod-Override header (which is what that helper inserts) is a workaround for that in the browser case, without you having to compromise the architecture of your application.